# Any way to speed up Redux store updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I've got some piece of functionality that I want to update very quickly. When I use local state, it updates pretty much immediately, the feedback is immediately visible to the user.

However I want to store this data so that the user can have this setting saved permanently (it also sends it to a database asynchronously via sagas, but that doesn't seem to be related to the slowdown)

The slowness seems to be related to saving it to my Redux store.

I am trying to figure out how to optimize it - I am currently using a relatively large Redux object (about 60 parameters) which may very well be the issue, even though I've read that increasing the size of an object stored in Redux shouldn't cause any issues.

My code to update the object looks like this:

```
export const settingsSave = (settings: object) => {
  return {
    type: Actions.SETTINGS_SAVE,
    payload: settings,
  };
};
```

And the data I am trying to update in it is just a standard boolean.

```
props.settingsSave({
    sentence_collapse: !props.settings.sentence_collapse,
 });
```

Is there any way to speed this operation up, besides breaking up the large object into smaller objects (which would be a headache, as it is stored all on the same data related to user settings in my backend).

I tried this:

```
const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(props.settings.sentence_collapse);
```

And then tried to have the actual user interface element controlled by the local state, whilst updating global state in the background, but this seemed to lead to the same slowness.

Is there some sort of principle I am missing for React/Redux here for faster speed?

Comment: It kinda implies that you have too many components selecting too big parts of the store, leading to too many rerenders. How are you reading data out of the store and how many components do so?

(also, generally, you are using a very outdated style of Redux here... you might want to read https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today )

Comment: Yeah, I intend to migrate to RTK at some point - this is a side project app and I don't have the time to upgrade everything in it yet. And yeah, that's what I'm thinking, it might be a re-render issue too. I have MANY components using the settings state - 20 or so on the page in question. Is there a good way around this besides splitting settings into separate objects?

Comment: Generally: don't select the full setting state, but only the properties your component actually needs. Then they will only rerender when those properties change.

Comment: How would you select only part of the state object? I have it as part of my Redux store with 60 items, but I am happy to reduce the state given to the components to only those necessary

Comment: I asked you to show code twice already didn't I? I have no idea how you do it right now.